# Fetching database content from notion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

According to the Notion [API](http://%20https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query), to retrieve the contents of your database you need to perform a post request. I’m trying to build an app that fetches the content from a database I’ve created on [Notion](https://ibb.co/k62yG6S) through its API and displayed it in a table view. How can I do this since it’s not a get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the networking logic set up, all you have to do is add this line of code, (change "request" object name with whatever you named it):

```
 request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

Here is an example of how to do a post network call: https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/http-post-request-example-in-swift/